# How to connect laravel App to Alfresco webdav?

Tags: laravel, alfresco, webdav

A part of my app consist of uploading files which I would like to stock them in alfresco. In order to do this, I have to connect my laravel app with alfresco using alfresco api or using webdav.
I already found a repository `pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-webdav` but I couldn't implement it. 

Is there anyone have already worked with webdav in laravel? Or Alfresco APIs in general with laravel ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use Alfresco's REST APIs?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Apache Chemistry PHP client](https://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html). It can connect to Alfresco as well as many other types of content repositories.

That client hasn't been updated in a while, so if you come across problems, report the issue, of course, but then you might decide to use the Apache Chemistry JSON binding in Alfresco directly.

If CMIS, the standard that Apache Chemistry implements, isn't doing it for you, consider using the [Alfresco REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com). That particular API is new in 5.2 so if you are using an older version it probably won't work.

If all else fails, you can always add your own RESTful endpoint to Alfresco using the [Web Script Framework](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/ws-overview.html). Then you can invoke those from your Laravel app.